# Login perzonalizado con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un inconveniente con la autenticación de usuarios de laravel...
pues para la empresa que tengo que desarrollo el sistema ya tiene una tabla en donde están los usuarios... cambiar el nombre de la tabla por defecto de laravel no fue un problema... pero ahora tengo que lidiar con que los campos username y password no existen.. tienen otro nombre que son USUARIO Y PASSWORD, con mayúsculas... laravel no me detecta el nombre de los campos y ya me quede sin ideas para poder solucionar esto.. estoy usando laravel 5.2
Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Postea algo de código o sino será difícil comprender cual es el problema

Comment: Si, tiene tiempo que no veo la estructura de archivos de laravel y desearía ser de más ayuda, pero para darte una idea, tienes que buscar en las librerías de laravel en donde establece los nombres de campo de usuario, y después vas a sobreescribir ese método con los nombres de tus campos.

Comment: Hola, estoy entendiendo que necesitas un custom guard. Para ello te recomiendo esta lectura: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-authentication-guard-in-laravel--cms-29667

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vfIXJsqrIo Esto  puede ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cambiar el nombre de usuario tendrías que modificar el método `username()` en tu **LoginController.php**

```
public function username()
{
    return 'USUARIO';
}
```

Y para cambiar el nombre de la contraseña, puedes definir un "[accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)" en **App\User.php**:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->PASSWORD;
}
```

**login.blade.php** : Reemplaza el `<input type="email" name="email">` por un `<input type="text" name="USUARIO">` pero el input de la contraseña se queda como está, así que **NO** lo cambies.

Comment: probe como dijiste y funciono! gracias